# rails CSVファイルをseedにてDBに入れたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

rails６でアプリケーションを作っています。

DBに入れるデータをCSVファイルで作成し、seedでデータが入るようにしていたところ、エラーが発生し、つまづいております。
ご教授いただけたら幸いです。

terminalでのエラー文

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Products
/Users/user/projects/medipra/db/seeds.rb:12:in `block in <main>'
/Users/user/projects/medipra/db/seeds.rb:11:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

seeds.rbのコード

```
require "csv"
date = "2019-11-11"

CSV.foreach('db/y_ALL20191015.csv') do |info|
  Products.create(change_category: info[0], master_type: info[1], pharmaceutical_code: info[2], kanji_significant_digits: info[3], name: info[4], kana_significant_digits: info[5], kana_name: info[6], unit_code: info[7], unit_significant_digits: info[8],
    unit_name: info[9],
    price_type: info[10],
    price: info[11],
    spare_1: info[12],
    n_p_s_p_drugs: info[13],
    nerve_destroyer: info[14],
    biologics: info[15],
    generic: info[16],
    spare_2: info[17],
    dental_drugs: info[18],
    contrast_agent: info[19],
    injection_volume: info[20],
    listing_type: info[21],
    product_name_relations: info[22],
    old_price_type: info[23],
    old_price: info[24],
    name_chnage_category: info[25],
    kana_name_change_category: info[26],
    dosage_form: info[27],
    spare_3: info[28],
    changed_date: info[29],
    abolition_date: info[30],
    standard_code: info[31],
    order_number: info[32],
    expiration_date: info[33],
    standard_name: info[34],
    created_at: date,
    updated_at: date
  )
end
```

DBにProductsテーブルは作成済みで、それぞれカラムもマイグレーションしてあります。

追記
db/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_11_10_125708) do

  create_table "products", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "change_category"
    t.string "master_type"
    t.integer "pharmaceutical_code"
    t.integer "kanji_significant_digits"
    t.string "name　"
    t.integer "kana_significant_digits"
    t.string "kana_name"
```

nameの後に意味不明なスペースが入ってますね。
多分これが原因です。

Comment: `Products`は`Product`ではないでしょうか？　Railsではモデルのクラス名は通常単数形です。`app/model/product.rb`があると思いますので、中身を確認してみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！単純なことを見落としてました。

Comment: ただ、また違うエラーが出てしまいました。 `unknown attribute 'name' for Product.`

Comment: DBのproductsテーブルに、nameカラムがない可能性があります。`db/schema.rb`を確認して、`products`テーブルに`name`があるかどうか確認してください。よくわからなかったら、質問文を編集して、`db/schema.rb`の内容を追記してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
schema.rbを確認したところ、nameの後ろに意味不明なスペースが入っていたため、マイグレーションファイルを編集してseedしたところ、無事にデータが入りました。
ご指摘ありがとうございました！！

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでは「自己回答」もOKですので、解決に至った情報を(コメントの内容を踏まえて)ご自身で投稿して頂くと、他のユーザーの助けにもなると思います。

Answer (score 1):

コメントなどにも記載の通り、nameの後ろのスペースが原因でカラムがうまく入らず、
それによるエラーでした。

全角スペースは目立つように設定してあったと思うのですが、うまくできていなかった模様。